# Use of REFERENCES keyword in MySQL

Tags: mysql, reference, foreign-keys, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following table definition in MySQL. It represents M:N relationship between the tables **Licenses** and **License Server**.

```
create table if not exists  served_license
(
    served_license_id       smallint            not null,
    version                 varchar(16)         not null,
    quantity                smallint            not null,
    expiry_date             char(16)            not null,
    license_server_id       tinyint             not null    references  license_server(license_server_id),
    license_id              varchar(64)         not null    references  license(feature, product),
    primary key (served_license_id)
);
```

Is this the correct usage of the keyword **REFERENCES**? If I change the table definition to the one below, will the columns behave differently?

```
create table if not exists  served_license
(
    served_license_id       smallint            not null,
    version                 varchar(16)         not null,
    quantity                smallint            not null,
    expiry_date             char(16)            not null,
    license_server_id       tinyint             not null,
    license_id              varchar(64)         not null,
    primary key (served_license_id),
    foreign key (license_server_id) references  license_server(license_server_id),
    foreign key (license_id) references license(feature, product)
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL only processes `REFERENCES` clauses when they're part of a `FOREIGN KEY` specification. Here's the quote from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

> MySQL parses but ignores “inline `REFERENCES` specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts `REFERENCES` clauses only when specified as part of a separate `FOREIGN KEY` specification.

So the first version will not enforce the foreign key relationships, the second version will (assuming you're using the `InnoDB` storage engine).

Comment: Thanks much for the clarification.